# Why is it a contradiction here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The exercise is in the picture, does $h'(u)=2x$ imply a contradiction because it's a function of $x$ and not $u$? or because $h(u)$ was defined as a constant in the equation of $\phi(x,u)$ and now its derivative is not $0$?

Comment: $h(u)$ is  a  function of $u$ only it can't be equal to $2x$ as required. The DE is not exact.

Comment: More specifically, when you integrate $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} = -u, h$ is the constant of integration, which is constant with respect to $x$, but may be a function of $u$. However, in the second equation, we find its derivative with respect to $u$ is a function of $x$, thus $h$ isn't constant with respect to $x$. This is the contradiction.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense now.